# Complete Genomics Junction file for SV Detection

Tags: vcf, genomics, structural-variation

At present, I have vcf file for each patient generated from tumor data. I am using virtual normal correction method for somatic mutation detection because I don't have normal data. For SNP or small variants detection, I have already converted vcf into tsv format but for SV, I need complete genomics junction file or high confidence junction beta file. Basically this file is used to represent SVs in the subject sequence. Look at the following pics for better idea :

[image: SV File Structure. Junction file is nothing but alljunctionbeta-[ASM-ID].tsv in the above image.]

and the header of the file is

```
ID    LeftChr    LeftPosition    LeftStrand    LeftLength    RightChr    RightPosition    RightStrand    RightLength StrandConsistent    Interchromosomal    Distance    DiscordantMatePairAlignment    ...
```

This file is specially generated and used by the company ["Complete Genomics"](http://www.completegenomics.com/). This file format is basically used in SV representation. I have no idea about the meaning of junction. For more information, look at Data type [http://www.bx.psu.edu/~giardine/tests/tmp/DataFileFormats112.pdf].

My question is how can I generate cg junction file from the given vcf and bam file.Can anybody tell me how to get it?

Thanks.

p.s. I'm aware that Complete Genomics was acquired by BGI in $117.6M. Now the paper I am trying to understand can be obtained from [this github link](https://github.com/shiltemann/Virtual-Normal-Correction) because I don't have matched normal data. In order to identify SVs, I need cg junction file. I don't know how to get it. That's why I am looking here for some help. Thanks.